# The Treelist's Sitecore query should show all items from a folder and restrict selection to a specific template

Tags: sitecore-client

Is there Sitecore datasource query for a Treelist to display all items from a specific folder, while limiting selection to only items of a particular template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep.

`DataSource=/Sitecore/Content/Home&IncludeTemplatesForSelection=section,page`

Where `section` and `page` in this case, would be the templates you wanted to include.

More information here: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/92/sitecore-experience-manager/controlling-the-list-of-items-in-a-selection-field.html

Comment: Thank you @Mark Cassidy, it worked like a charm!!